# QT QsciScintilla crash

Tags: qt, qscintilla

I'm using QScintilla 2.8.
I have properly build the qscintilla2.dll.
I put it in my c:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\mingw48_32\bin folder

My path is the setup that Qt sets:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\mingw48_32\lib;
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\mingw48_32\bin;
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin;
```

In my project i put the following in my .pro file:
    LIBS += -lqscintilla2

In my code:

```
#include <Qsci/qsciscintilla.h>
#include <Qsci/qscilexerhtml.h>
#include <Qsci/qscilexerjavascript.h>
#include <Qsci/qscilexerxml.h>
#include <Qsci/qscilexercss.h>
#include <Qsci/qscilexersql.h>
#include <Qsci/qscilexeryaml.h>

...
QsciScintilla *editor = new QsciScintilla();
```

The program compiles fine.  But when i run the program it crashes when it i step over:

```
QsciScintilla *editor = new QsciScintilla();
```

The error I see is in the Application output:
 QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget
 Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.

Also i get a message box that says:
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

***Update 4/2/2014 - 11:17 PM***
I moved the code just to see it it made a difference if i initialize it right after the application first loads

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  ..
}
```

so in MainWindow:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ...

    QsciScintilla *editor = new QsciScintilla();
    setCentralWidget(editor);

    ...
}
```

but it still fails with the same issues

***Update 4/3/2014 - 8:32 PM***
OK I think I figured it out.  When I build my project as a Release then everything works fine.  Its when I use build my project as Debug that it fails.  So maybe I need to build a debug version of QScintilla then

Any ideas.  I've googled but nothing comes up.
Thanks

Comment: So: what happens if you do the right thing and create a QApplication first?

Comment: I actually do create a QApplication first.  It has a treewidget with a list of files and when i select it i want to open it in the editor.  So I load the list of files on a QTreeWidget when i select it i want to load the file to QSciScintilla.  The code above was just to show that its crashing when initializaing.  I even move the code to see what happens when I initialize right after MainWindow() constructor and after ui->setupUi(this) and fails when QsciScintilla is hit

Comment: I updated my code to initialize it right when the application first loads to see if that would work.  I noted in the code above with the Update 4/2/2014 - 11:17 PM.  Still same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update 4/3/2014 - 8:32 PM***
My solution is to build a debug version of the library and all works great.  I used the following steps:

```
qmake qscintilla.pro
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug install
```

Note: Make sure to copy the qscintilla2.dll to the bin directory of where all the libs are.  In my case it in:

```
From:
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\mingw48_32\lib

To:
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\mingw48_32\bin
```